When a promise is returned from within a then() callback, does it replace the promise returned by the then() itself?
I’m trying to understand the inner workings of a promise chain. I know that a call to then() on a promise always returns a new promise.
When a promise is returned from within a then() callback, does it replace the promise returned by the then() itself? In other words, the inner promise supersedes the outer promise in the chain.
It would be good to know what this promise chain would actually look like flattened out:

function fetchData() {
  console.log("Fetching data...");
  return fetch('https://api.example.com/data1')
    .then(data1 => {
      console.log("Data 1 fetched");
      return fetch('https://api.example.com/data2');
    })
    .then(data2 => {
      console.log("Data 2 fetched");
      return { data1, data2 };
    });
}

Also a side-note, if I were to add a final call to then() in this code that does nothing but log something without returning, the promise that then() creates would be resolved with the data2 value?

In general, a promise wrapped in another promise is effectively equivalent to the inner promise. So I don't think it makes a difference whether it replaces it or not.

@Barmar makes difference when you store promises in a queue for example

The second .then call doesn't have data1 in its scope so you'll get undefined. When a promise is returned from a then callback, it is must first settle before the moving on to the next callback. If you need both responses in scope, you'd want move your .then on your inner fetch call. Async await allows you to handle this without nesting. MDN has a good write-up on the behaviour of promises

@AndrewGillis On the issue of accessing data1, refer to our canonical question How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?

"When a promise is returned from within a then() callback, does it replace the promise returned by the then() itself?" - no, an object cannot be "replaced" by a different object in JS. Promises are no magic. The two promises just will behave the same, by resolving to the same result (fulfilling with the same value or rejecting with the same reason), so they're equivalent in that regard, but they're still two separate objects.

"I I were to add a final call to then() in this code that does nothing but log something without returning, the promise that then() creates would be resolved with the data2 value?" - no. A function without an explicit return statement returns undefined when called, so that is the value that promise will fulfill with. It does not somehow fall back to the result of the previous promise.


When a promise is returned from within a then() callback, does it replace the promise returned by the then() itself?

No. The promise returned by the then itself has already been returned, so that represents a distinct object, which could even have been assigned to a variable. If so, this variable would not get a second assignment that replaces the object it first was referencing.
The two promises are distinct objects, but the first one gets "locked-in" to the second one. As the ECMA Script specification says:

A promise is resolved if it is settled or if it has been “locked in” to match the state of another promise.

In your code example there are these promise objects

Returned by the first fetch
Returned by the first then
Returned by the second then (equal to what fetchData returns)
Returned by the second fetch. The one returned by the first then is locked in to match its state.


if I were to add a final call to then() in this code that does nothing but log something without returning, the promise that then() creates would be resolved with the data2 value?

No, it wouldn't. The value you want that then() promise to resolve with should be returned by the then callback. If you only log something and don't return an explicit value, then the return value is undefined, which is what the promise will resolve with.
Other remarks
In your code you have a reference to data1 in the second then-callback that is not defined. The scope of the data1 variable is local to the first then callback.
If you wanted it to be passed along the promise chain, you should make sure it is part of the resolution value of each promise in the (downward) chain.
Secondly, fetch doesn't return the data yet, but a response object. You need to consume the data stream with a method like json(), and wait for the promise that this method returns.
Before async/await syntax was available, you'd do that like this (to avoid nested callbacks):
// Helper function
function getJson(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}

function fetchData() {
    console.log("Fetching data...");
    return getJson('https://api.example.com/data1').then(data1 => {
        console.log("Data 1 fetched");
        // Pass data1 down the promise chain
        return Promise.all([data1, getJson('https://api.example.com/data2')]);
    }).then(([data1, data2]) => {
        console.log("Data 2 fetched");
        return { data1, data2 };
    });
}

With async/await this scoping issue disappears:
async function fetchData() {
    console.log("Fetching data...");
    const data1 = await getJson('https://api.example.com/data1');
    console.log("Data 1 fetched");
    const data2 = await getJson('https://api.example.com/data2');
    console.log("Data 2 fetched");
    return { data1, data2 };
}

Finally, if the second request doesn't depend on the response of the first request, you could issue the second request without waiting for the first response:
async function fetchData() {
    console.log("Fetching data... (both requests)");
    const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([
        getJson('https://api.example.com/data1'),
        getJson('https://api.example.com/data2')
    ]);
    return { data1, data2 };
}


Thanks for putting me on to how a promise returned by then() will “lock in” and follow a promise returned in the fulfilled handler. This is the best explanation I’ve found: https://www.saurabhmisra.dev/promises-in-javascript-resolved-promise-fates/

@MattStyles, glad it was of use to you!
